# RabbitMq: Setting AMQP_AUTODELETE flag on Exchange with PHP AMQP

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqp

I'm trying to set AMQP_AUTODELETE flag on my exchange using  AMQPExchange::setFlags ( int $flags )

http://php.net/manual/en/amqp.constants.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpexchange.setflags.php

does not work... :(

```
$exchange = new \AMQPExchange(new \AMQPChannel($this->_connection));

$exchange->setName($name);
$exchange->setType(AMQP_EX_TYPE_FANOUT);

$exchange->setFlags(AMQP_AUTODELETE);
$exchange->declare();
```

$exchange->getFlags() returns 0 instead of 16 (integer value of AMQP_AUTODELETE).

But it works when I set AMQP_DURABLE flag the same way, $exchange->getFlags() returns 2.

Has anyone found a solution for this ? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMQP_AUTODELETE flag can only be used for AMQPQueue. 
See [the `AMQPExchange::setFlags` manual page](http://php.net/amqpexchange.setflags) for valid flags.

Comment: thanks, looks like I missed that setFlag currently considers only 2 types of flags...

Comment: This link is broken. Try [AMQPExchange::setFlags()](http://php.net/manual/pl/amqpexchange.setflags.php) and [AMQPQueue::setFlags()](http://php.net/manual/pl/amqpqueue.setflags.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Exchanges with auto-delete cannot be created using current php amqp module (v1.2.0).

There is [recent commit](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/pull/69/commits) in dev-master (1.4.0-dev) that is adding this functionality. Still, I was not able to make it work. I see that exchange object is having auto_delete attribute, but when it is declared, in rabbitmq (v3.1.3) it is having auto_delete flag set to false.

For now I will create cronjob, that will delete exchanges that don't have related queue.

This is answer for your question and also collaboration request. Any input about this topic is welcome.